# Xamarin UWP Views with equal names in different shared projects

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uwp

I'm trying to connect two shared projects to Xamarin UWP project. When building I got the following errors:

***CSC : error CS1508: Resource identifier 'Demo.UWP.App.xaml' has already been used in this assembly***

***1>CSC : error CS1508: Resource identifier 'Demo.UWP.Views.MainPage.xaml' has already been used in this assembly...***

I think this happens because both shared projects contains App.xaml and MainPage.xaml classes. They are in different namespaces (Shared1 and Shared2), but I'm afraid all views will are replacing in one namespace when building UWP.

Is there any possibilities to contain views with same classnames (though in different namespaces) in several shared projects which are referenced by one UWP project?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share a simple sample ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I've ran into the same issue and resolved it in the same way, it looks like a bug to me. Perhaps it is related to this change: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40077 (at least the new bug is not as bad as the old one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem.
It was connected with equal filenames, not classnames.
Changing App.xaml to "Proj2_app.xaml (and proj2_app.xaml.cs) resolves my issue.